# Azure Live Metrics doesn't show Incoming Request , Outgoing request, Server Health

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have followed below Microsoft documents to achieve Application Insights

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-agent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments

Just to give some background - My war is deployed in JBoss EAP 7 Standalone web server which is hosted in Azure Virtual machine.

But some reason I don't see Live Metrics at all, could you please guide how to enable ?

[image]

FYI - I can see all other metrics in AI

Comment: Were you able to solve this yet? If not, would it be possible to share a [Minimal, Reproducible Code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your app?

Answer (score 0):

I used to create a springboot web application with app insights [following this doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-java-applicationinsights)
And when I finished the code and configuration, I run the program in local environment, I can reach the 'live metric' page. When I stopped the program, the web page showed 'Not available: your app is offline or using an older SDK'.

So according to your description, I think you can make sure if you have started the web container first. Or you can debug your program in local environment to check your code and configuration. If the program runs well locally and still can't reach live metric, try to modify the pom.xml and use a newer version.

Comment: Yes. In local environment  I am able see the live metric page. However, the Wildfly which is running in Linux is not showing up.